When modifying document in another window, why do changes appear then vanish when using the return value of window.open() but not window.opener?
I have a webpage which opens a new window in the same domain, then I want to have the first window modify DOM properties in the second window.
Using window.opener works correctly, but I am actually using Typescript and this way is not type-safe.
I'm trying to change it to instead use the return value of window.open. The changes I make to the second window appear for a fraction of a second then go away.
This is Javascript in the browser only, nothing server-side.
Working way, using window.opener
This works correctly but is unsafe in Typescript.
You do not need a web server for this; you can open it in a browser using a file:// URL.
first.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>First window - using window.opener</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    // This global function is called from the second window.
    function onSecondWindowReady(paragraphElement) {
      document.body.append(`Received a ${paragraphElement.constructor.name} from the second window.`);
      paragraphElement.style.background = "yellow";
      paragraphElement.innerText += " It should be yellow now."
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const secondWindow = window.open("second.html", "secondWindow");
      if (!secondWindow) {
        document.body.append("Second window didn't open, please check web browser popup blocker.");
      }
    });
  </script>
  <p>This is the first window.</p>
</body>
</html>

second.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Second window - using window.opener</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      window.opener.onSecondWindowReady(document.querySelector("p"));
    });
  </script>
  <p>This is the second window.</p>
</body>
</html>

Expected result:

In the first window, the text "Received a HTMLParagraphElement from the second window" is added to the page.

In the second window, the text says "This is the second window. It should be yellow now" with a yellow background.


Non-working way, using return value of window.open()
You must use a web server for this. If you open it in a browser using file:// you'll get a cross-origin DOMException. The server just needs to serve static files, for example the Live Server extension for VS Code works.
first.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>First window - using window.open() return value</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const firstWindow = window;
      const secondWindow = window.open("second.html", "secondWindow");
      if (secondWindow) {

        function accessTheSecondWindow() {
          const paragraphElementInSecondWindow = secondWindow.document.querySelector("p");
          if (paragraphElementInSecondWindow) {
            firstWindow.document.body.append(`Found a <p> in the second window.`);
            paragraphElementInSecondWindow.style.background = "yellow";
            paragraphElementInSecondWindow.innerText += " It should be yellow now.";
          } else {
            // Sometimes happens due to dev server caching or live reload?
            firstWindow.document.body.append("Couldn't find a <p> element in the second window, please reload this page.");
          }
        }

        if (secondWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
          firstWindow.document.body.append("The second window already finished loading. ");
          accessTheSecondWindow();
        } else {
          firstWindow.document.body.append("The second window is still loading, adding event listener. ");
          secondWindow.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            firstWindow.document.body.append("DOMContentLoaded event fired in second window. ");
            accessTheSecondWindow();
          });
        }
      } else {
        document.body.append("Second window didn't open, please check web browser popup blocker.");
      }
    });
  </script>
  <p>This is the first window.</p>
</body>
</html>

second.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Second window - using window.open() return value</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is the second window.</p>
</body>
</html>

Expected result: same as in the previous section.
Actual result:

In the first window, the text "Found a <p> in the second window." is added to the page.
In the second window, the text "It should be yellow now" appears and the background is yellow for a short time, then the text and background color are removed.
Reloading first.html causes the text and color to reappear then vanish in the second window.
Tested in Firefox and Chrome on Windows, with extensions disabled.
16-second screen recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTT-JUEb_UI

How can I make the changes stay?

Because when you reload the first page, the WindowProxy you get access when doing window.open("second.html", "secondWindow") is actually pointing to the previous Window object, that got loaded at your previous loading.
Only after, that Window will navigate to the new location, which happens to be the same, and load a new, fresh document, without the changes you made.
You can verify this by making the second page write the current time in the <p> and log its content in the first page when you access it.
This is mainly due to the second param of open(url, name) which will use the same tab for both contexts.

I'm not entirely sure why using opener is an issue in your case, but maybe you could use a shake-hand system in place instead, using postMessage().
